# Responsiveness in MJML <mj-attributes>

Tags: mjml

When using MJML to create the email templates, it provides the carousel feature in email templates. Here is the code from the their sample. (`icon-width` and `tb-width` were added by me)

```
<mj-carousel icon-width="30px" tb-width="20px">
   <mj-carousel-image src="https://www.mailjet.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/ecommerce-guide.jpg" />
   <mj-carousel-image src="https://www.mailjet.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/3@1x.png" />
   <mj-carousel-image src="https://www.mailjet.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/1@1x.png" />
</mj-carousel>
```

As you see, the attribute `tb-width` controls the width thumbnails of the carousel, I want to change the value of `tb-width` to be smaller when it goes into mobile screen, otherwise I will have to stick to one value cross all screen sizes.

I tried this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
   [tb-width] {
      width: 50px !important;
   } // this is not working
}
```

Then I tried this based on the [official document](https://mjml.io/documentation/#mjml-style)

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
   div[style*="tb-width:20px;"] {
      width: 300px !important;
   }
}
```

None of above code works.

How do you guys solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @dermothghes from mjml slack channel, here is the solution:

All these mjml components will have a corresponded css class in the outputted HTML, what we need to do is to compile the *.**mjml*** file first and find the corresponded css class from the output.

In my question, this should work:

```
 @media all and (max-width: 480px) {
    .mj-carousel-thumbnail {
       width: 50px !important;
    }
 }
```

`.mj-carousel-thumbnail` is the generated class from `mj-carousel-thumbnail` mjml component.